# Checking off checkbox when record gets focus

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox, toggle

I'm guessing this has been answered before but I cant seem to word it right to find help.

Anyways, I'm using a barcode scanner in access to find records (it just enters the number in a textbox then hits enter). What I need is to make it so that when a record is found (using rs.FindFirst), the check box field (Named "Audit Check") gets checked off.

Here is my code for the search, I have a feeling that it can be incorporated into this event.

```
Private Sub BarcodeBox_AfterUpdate()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

If Not IsNull(Me![Barcodebox]) Then
  Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
  rs.FindFirst "[Barcode] = '" & Me![Barcodebox] & "'"
  If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
Else
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
  If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
```

to

```
If Not rs.EOF Then 
Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
Me.MyCheckbox = True
End If
```

Comment: Tried this, I got a compile error: Method or data member not found
Do I need to change the Me.MyCheckBox to something else?

Comment: The name of your checkbox object.  You didn't mention what it was called on your form.  I assumed "Audit Check" was your field name in your table, but if that's the name of the checkbox object just make sure you use brackets because it has a space in it (i.e. me.[Audit Check])

Comment: Thats what I thought, thanks so much Johnny. Its working great except for 1 issue. If a barcode gets scanned that isn't there, it gives a runtime error '3020': Update or cancel update without AddNew or Edit. Is there a way to fix this error so that instead gives a msgbox that says barcode not found?

Comment: That sounds like it's coming from a different routine, because there's no "Update" statement in the sub you posted.  When that error comes up again, hold down the "CTRL" key and hit the "Pause/Break" key.  That will break the code.  You should get a box that says "Debug".  Click that button and see where the code is breaking.

Comment: Figured it out, by switching the rs.EOF to NoMatch, it ends the sub before the checkbox=True can be run and break the code. Thanks so much for all the help Johnny!

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider upvoting it or giving it the Accepted Answer checkmark (or both) so that if anyone else has the same issue they'll know the answer solved the problem.